# Resolving a number to a specific group

Tags: php, oop

I'm making a web application for calculating road tax data. For this, the price can rely on the vehicle's weight.

The data i received is something like this:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 57,
    'yearly' => 228,
  ),
  12000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 62,
    'yearly' => 248,
  ),
  13000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 68,
    'yearly' => 272,
  ),
  14000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 74,
    'yearly' => 296,
  ),
  15000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 79,
    'yearly' => 316,
  ),
  16000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 85,
    'yearly' => 340,
  ),
  17000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 91,
    'yearly' => 364,
  ),
  18000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 97,
    'yearly' => 388,
  ),
  19000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 102,
    'yearly' => 408,
  ),
  20000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 108,
    'yearly' => 432,
  ),
  21000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 114,
    'yearly' => 456,
  ),
  22000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 119,
    'yearly' => 476,
  ),
  23000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 125,
    'yearly' => 500,
  ),
  24000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 131,
    'yearly' => 524,
  ),
  25000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 137,
    'yearly' => 548,
  ),
  26000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 142,
    'yearly' => 568,
  ),
  27000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 148,
    'yearly' => 592,
  ),
  28000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 154,
    'yearly' => 616,
  ),
  29000 => 
  array (
    'quarterly' => 159,
    'yearly' => 636,
  )
);
```

The numbers (first item in array, `1`, `1051`, `1151`, `1251`, `1351`, 1451`,` etc) are the weight classes, i need to check the user's vehicle weight and check to which weight class it belongs.

For example, i have an vehicle which weights 600 KG, this vehicle belongs to the weight class `1`.

If i have an example which weights 1150 KG, it belongs to the weight class `1051`.

For calculating this, i use this method:

```
public static function resolveWeightClass(array $data, $vehicleWeight) {
    $weightClasses = array_keys($data);
    for ($weightClassIndex = 0; $weightClassIndex < count($weightClasses); $weightClassIndex++) {
        $weightClass = $weightClasses[$weightClassIndex];

        if ($weightClass < $vehicleWeight) {
            continue;
        }
        return $weightClass;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- The `data` parameter is where all the array keys exist from the weight classes.
- The `vehicleWeight` parameter is the vehicle's weight.

**Problem**

When I run this code, and the vehicle is for example `16500` KG's, the code still chooses the `17000` weight class, when i need the `16000` weight class.

**Question**

How do I make my code so that it will choose the right weight class incase of the weight class after it.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean with the or the next weight class doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
public static function resolveWeightClass(array $data, $vehicleWeight) {
    $weightClasses = array_keys($data);
    sort($weightClasses);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($weightClasses) - 1; $i++) {
        if($weightClasses[$i+1] > $vehicleWeight) {
            return $weightClasses[$i];
        }
    }
    return $weightClasses[$i];
}
```

The code iterates over the sorted keys and checks whether the next key is already over vehicle weight. If it is, it returns data for the current key.

Comment: But what if the next weight class does'nt exist?

Comment: In that case it returns the last class.

Comment: But it would throw an error right, that the array key can't be found.

Comment: It shouldn't since you iterate only through indexes 0..n-1. This way you make sure that the next key always exists.

Comment: But, it shouldn't sort it. Because there's nothing wrong with the data right

Comment: That depends on your data. If it's already sorted, you don't need to sort it again. But if it's not, the code will not work properly.

Comment: I see, i just noticed this but why are you using count(...) - 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69827/discussion-between-bas-and-michal-kralik).

Answer (score 1):

This might be the answer you're looking for:

```
<?php
public static function resolveWeightClass(array $data, $vehicleWeight) {
    $weightClasses = array_keys($data);
    for ($weightClassIndex = 0; $weightClassIndex < count($weightClasses); $weightClassIndex++) {
        $weightClass = $weightClasses[$weightClassIndex];
        $nextWeightClass = (isset($weightClasses[$weightClassIndex+1]) ? $weightClasses[$weightClassIndex+1] : 99999999999);

        if (($weightClass <= $vehicleWeight) && ($nextWeightClass > $vehicleWeight)) {
            return $weightClass;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: But when you take a weight class wich is higher then the highest array index? Then it returns the 0 value. Which should be the last found value?

Comment: The `isset()` condition will give a true or false to the key's existance without causing an error. If it returns true, it loads the next weight class, if it's false it goes for something that is unlikely to be beaten (i.e. 999999999)